# Git cannot find local repository $ on desktop

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, git-tf

I am trying to clone connect a TFS server into my local desktop git repository. How do I resolve error below? I am trying to connect to local C:\ with a dollar sign.

```
git tfs clone "https://testserver.com/abcd/collection/" $/source/gittest --deep
```

**Error:**

```
The item $/source/gittest was not found in the repository.
```

**Background:**

in **C:\Source\gittest**

I wrote

`git init`

`git add`    (comment: added some test source control files)

`git commit`

Comment: Use `git-tfs`, not `git-tf`. `git-tf` is no longer maintained and is less capable than `git-tfs`.

Comment: exactly, just learned that the hard way

Answer (score 0):

I went into directory C:\Source\gittest and removed the directory path (excluded source/gittest)

**Command below:**

```
git-tf clone "https://testserver.com/abcd/collection/" $/ --deep
```